# How to concatenate 2 lists of numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I have 2 lists `l1`, `l2` that contain 5 numpy arrays each of the following shapes:

```
[(32, 84, 84, 1), (32,), (32,), (32,), (32, 84, 84, 1)]
```

The result I want is achieved using:

```
[np.concatenate(item) for item in zip(l1, l2)]
```

The resulting shapes are (which are the expected / desired result)

```
[(64, 84, 84, 1), (64,), (64,), (64,), (64, 84, 84, 1)]
```

However when I try to concatenate them directly using `np.concatenate(l1, l2)`, I get an error:

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (32,84,84,1) into shape (32)
```

So I expand dims for the middle 3 arrays in each `l1` and `l2`, the resulting shapes are:

```
[(32, 84, 84, 1), (1, 32), (1, 32), (1, 32), (32, 84, 84, 1)]
```

I then try to concatenate again:

```
np.concatenate((l1, l2))
```

And the resulting shapes are:

```
[(32, 84, 84, 1),
 (1, 32),
 (1, 32),
 (1, 32),
 (32, 84, 84, 1),
 (32, 84, 84, 1),
 (1, 32),
 (1, 32),
 (1, 32),
 (32, 84, 84, 1)]
```

And trying with `np.concatenate((l1, l2), axis=1)` results in the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3418, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-111-0928bf6cff84>", line 1, in <module>
    ccc = np.concatenate((aaa, bbb), axis=1)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in concatenate
numpy.AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1
```

So, is there a way to do it without a for loop?

Comment: can you give the sample input for l1 and l2? Is there a particular reason you want to avoid a for loop?

Comment: If your desired result is a list of arrays with different shapes, why are you playing tricks to avoid the obvious loop?

Comment: @Chris Doyle You may use `np.random.random()` and specify the shapes I mentioned and try yourself, it won't make a difference what the values are.

Comment: @hpaulj It can be a numpy array or a list I don't care

Comment: but we are trying to understand whats the purpose or advantage to avoiding using a for loop.

Comment: @Chris Doyle It's more efficient I guess and why I care because it's going to be called a lot in my code so the faster, the better

Comment: It would be an object dtype array, which is slower.  The fast numpy stuff is for numeric calculations, not for object or list substitutes.

Comment: @hpaulj so you're suggesting that I close the question and stick with the for loop?

Comment: But what makes you think a for loop is not efficient? list comprehensions in python are pretty fast. Sure you can choose other things like `map(np.concatenate, zip(l1, l2))` but under the hood its still going to have to iterate all the items returned from zip and apply the np function to them. you seem to be under the impression that for loops must just be slow. if you run it and find a bottle neck or performance problem them re-evaluate the issue. but given your current scenario your always going to have to iterate over the items and for loops are pretty efficient at that

Comment: @Chris Doyle I'm just making sure that there is no numpy function that can achieve the same result, otherwise i'll stick with for loops, they are fast enough I agree with that

Comment: `np.concatenate(l(1, l2))` tries to make `l1` and `l2` arrays, so it can  do the usual join.  It does work diectly on lists.  `np.array(l1)` is producing the error.

Comment: @Chris Doyle I tried `np.stack()` still the same issue, if they are not the same thing and it will be faster than for loops, then maybe.

Answer (score 1):

An ndarray is a (usually fixed-size) multidimensional container of items of the **same type and size**

So you can't convert your list (of numpy arrays) into ndarray with np.array() call.

Also, np.concatenate returns ndarray, so because of the above reason, you can't apply that function on your list as well (but applying to each item in the list works, like you have already found out).

So if you have to avoid explicit looping for some reason, use map as pointed out by @ChrisDoyle in comments:

```
map(np.concatenate, zip(l1, l2))
```

[The N-dimensional array (ndarray)](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.ndarray.html#arrays-ndarray)

Comment: thanks, it won't matter much because as @Chris Doyle indicated in the comments, it would be using a for loop under the hood to iterate over them, so it's the same thing.